# cant connect to Mysql from container deployed from joomla image

Tags: docker, joomla, containers

I have installed docker on amazon linux and deployed mysql container with version 8.0

Now I run joomla container using following command to run and link the container with mysql container

```
docker run -d  --name myjoomlasite --link mysqlserver:mysql  -e  JOOMLA_DB_PASSWORD=Muneesh@17 -e  JOOMLA_DB_USER=joomladb_user -e JOOMLA_DB_NAME=joomladb joomla
```

I am able to create the container and able to access the mysql server but it exited after some time and getting following error in docker logs

```
Error executing 'postInstallation': Failed to connect to mariadb:3306 after 36 tries
```

NOte: I am able to run the wordpress and drupal on the same server without any issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is mysqlserver:mysql? a container name? Show more please.

Comment: mysqlserver is name of my mysql container maping with joomla container.

Comment: Then, why it will visit `mariadb:3306`, not `mysql:3306`?

Comment: i dont know...since Iam new to docker..Iam not much aware of that...I try to built container using bitnami joomala image..?Does bitnami only compatible with mariadb?

Comment: Once I built the container..I am able to enter the joomla container and from which I can connect to mysqlserver..however after few minutes it excited throwing above mentioned error?

Comment: I'm not sure we are talking about the same thing. But `mysqlserver:mysql` is your --link use, you set a alias has the name `mysql` for the container `mysqlserver`, so you need to use `mysql:3306` to visit. If you want to use `mariadb:3306` to visit, you should use `--link mysqlserver:mariadb`.

Comment: I try the same but getting error. when I run the container I am to create. when seeing the container log it throws following error https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img924/4892/FwY75P.jpg

Comment: after login to container..I am able  to connect to mysql container from joomla container..However I am not able to understand why it throws the error and exit. please find the screenshot from the link https://imagizer.imageshack.com/img921/9488/i1oCUn.jpg

Comment: I didn't see you modify to use `--link mysqlserver:mariadb` ...

Comment: now MySQL server is connecting  but throws some new error..any idea on this 

` mysql-c ERROR [canConnect] Connection with 'bn_joomla' user is unsuccessful`
`Error executing 'postInstallation': Cannot connect to MySQL server:
MySQL command failed to run. Error:
 ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bn_joomla'@'172.17.0.5' (using password: NO)`

Comment: If you are working with Joomla, it makes sense to join us at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.